# how can a user pass a textfiled value to a combobox in another form

Tags: java

i have a textfiled in a form where user enters the text and the user then clicks on a button on the form where the value entered in the textfield is reflected to a combo box in another form.How do i code it?

Comment: are you using Swing or JavaFX?

Comment: Is it Java AWT?

Comment: If you mean TextField, you can write
String s = field.getText();
where field references your TextField

Comment: @Amarildo am using Swing

Comment: @DimaRich yes am using the java awt